# Backup ssh de un servidor a otro

Tags: ssh, sftp

Tengo un problema es la 1ra vez que me pasa asi que soy complementamente inexperto en el asunto, uno de los servidores que tenia contratado, lamentablemente se daño, y solo puedo acceder a el mediante consola.

Adquiri otro servidor, y quiero pasar mi informacion del servidor dañado al nuevo.

Contando con que en el servidor dañado estoy en modo
root@sysresccd

¿Que pasos me recomiendan? con el fin de poder recuperar mi información y trasladarla.

Gracias y perdonad el abuso.

Comment: que deseas pasar especificamente? ya que tu pregunta es demaciado global!

Comment: Una archivo o carpeta en especifica, donde se encuentran almacenados Videos y Pdf´s

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo de varias formas:
**con scp:** version copy segura utiliza ssh

```
// recibir desde  el servidor remoto a la carpeta de igual nombre
scp -r root@sysresccd:/tufolder/videos /tufolder/videos 
// enviar al servidor remoto a la carpeta de igual nombre
scp -r  /tufolder/videos root@sysresccd:/tufolder/videos
```

**con sftp:** version ftp segura utiliza ssh

```
// no situamos en el directorio /tufolder/videos en el nuevo servidor
sftp root@sysresccd
cd /tufolder/videos
mget *
```

**con rsync:** version segura utiliza ssh

```
// desde el servidor viejo
rsync -e ssh -avz root@sysresccd:/tufolder/videos /tufolder/videos
```

**otras posibles opciones:**

- nfs
- ftp
- samba